# Why do jobs using gitlab resource_groups not get started when they are ready?

Tags: git, gitlab, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci

I am facing problem with my pipeline design using gitlab resource groups. See here my simple reduced .gitlab-ci.yml:

```
stages:
  - pre-build
  - build
  - test


pre-build:
  stage: pre-build
  script:
    - echo "Pre build"
    - sleep 5

build:
  stage: build
  needs: [pre-build]
  script:
    - sleep 100

test:
  stage: test
  needs: [pre-build, build]
  script:
    - echo "Test on hardware"
    - sleep 40
  resource_group: test-resource
```

What I want to achieve:

- The test hardware is not able to process multiple processes in parallel, so I want to run only one pipeline at a time on this hardware
- I use the resource group in the last stage to achieve this
- The idea: the test takes a lot of time, if there are for example multiple commits made during the test time, I want to test the newest one once the test on the hardware is finished.

The problem I am facing:
Lets use the example from the gitlab file above. If you do a commit 'A', the pipeline starts to run and reaches the test job after app. 105 seconds. The thing is: If you do another commit 'B' **during these 105 seconds**, something interesting happens:
When 'A' would ready to start its test job, it will **not** do that as commit 'B' already created a newer job which is pulling the resource group.

[image]

In our real development pipeline, the build takes app. 1,5h. This means, if during this time another commit is made (which is very likely), we never enter the test job / test stage.

Does anyone have similar issues, or am I doing something wrong? We solved this problem by implementing a trigger of a downstream gitlab yaml file, but I would like to avoid this if possible.

Comment: Did you set the 'process mode' of the resource group by any chance?

Comment: Hi! Sure, see:

curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: ***" "https://***/<project_id>/resource_groups"
...{"id":155,"key":"test-resource","process_mode":"newest_first","created_at":"2022-10-11T17:39:36.529+02:00","updated_at":"2022-10-18T14:47:52.329+02:00"},....

Answer (score 0):

> Why do jobs using Gitlab resource_groups not get started when they are ready?

Because when you use the ["Newest first" process mode](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/resource_groups/#process-modes), it will pick the first job from the list of upcoming jobs with a status of either `created`, `scheduled` or `waiting_for_resource`.

> am I doing something wrong?

I don't think you're doing anything wrong. I think this is the intended behaviour of the process mode unfortunately.

> Does anyone have similar issues?

I see there's an [issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/362844) on the Gitlab issue tracker that describes this problem. I completely agree with this quote by the author of the issue:

> The behavior of including `created` seems to change the definition of the `resource_group` a bit beyond a lock since those jobs are not actively in contention for the lock, but are still blocking other jobs from obtaining it.

So because the resource will select `created` jobs, the process mode is not just blocking concurrent runs, but also preventing older jobs from running if a newer one has been `created` (and not necessarily even running yet).